# How can I get JAXB2 to emit CamelCase bindings?

Tags: java, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin, java-ws

I'm generating Java classes from a WSDL using the jaxws-maven-plugin's [wsimport](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) goal. Out of the box, this generates hideous classes and methods from the XML schema; e.g., a class called MYOBJECT from an XML element named MY_OBJECT.

I've found that I can [customize my JAXB2 bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) with an external file; this would be acceptable for a small number of classes and methods, but the overhead of manually naming everything in this case is undesirable.

Some searching uncovers references to an [XJC CamelCase Always](http://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/sources/svn0/content/trunk/www/camelcase-always/index.html?rev=339) plugin, but this appears to be unmaintained and most links are 404s. Not willing to give up, I did find a [camelcase-always](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/releases/org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons/camelcase-always/1.0) Maven artifact which appears to provide this functionality, but I'm not sure how to configure this so that jaxws-maven-plugin uses it.

How can I get CamelCase bindings without specifying them all manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find examples of how to do this with `jaxws-maven-plugin`, but I did find examples using the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

First, you need a repository added to your POM:

```
<repository>
    <id>releases</id>
    <name>Releases</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
```

Note the plugin declaration and arguments added to the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` execution.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jaxb-generate</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <generatePackage>YOUR.PACKAGE.HERE</generatePackage>
        <args>
            <arg>-camelcase-always</arg>
        </args>
        <bindingDirectory>src/main/binding</bindingDirectory>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>http://YOUR.WSDL.HERE</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>camelcase-always</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See the [docs](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/Maven+JAXB2+Plugin) for more details.

Comment: The `camelcase-always` plugin is going to be integrated in `jaxb2-basics` with this [PR](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/pull/461) with others plugins from the `org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons` groupId

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful for users of Apache CXF and the cxf-xjc-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <extensions>
        <extension>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons:camelcase-always:1.0</extension>
      </extensions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
          <xsdOptions>
            <xsdOption>
              <xsd>YOUR.XSD.HERE</xsd>
              <packagename>YOUR.PACKAGE.HERE</packagename>
              <extensionArgs>
                <extensionArg>-camelcase-always</extensionArg>
              </extensionArgs>
              <extension>true</extension>
            </xsdOption>
          </xsdOptions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```