# How to customize property name in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am using JAXB to generate java classes based on some XSD schemas. For an element such as:

`<xsd:element name="REC_LOC" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>`

jaxb generates the following code:

```
@XmlElement(name = "REC_LOC", required = true)
protected String recloc;

public String getRECLOC() {
    return recloc;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the recloc property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setRECLOC(String value) {
    this.recloc = value;
}
```

The problem is that we need to use some proprietary XML tools that rely on the naming convention of the getter/setter methods. For example, for the field REC_LOC they expect methods called getRecLoc(String value) and setRecLoc(), instead of getRECLOC().

Is there any way to customise the method names generated by jaxb?

Comment: you can always write class code by yourself and use @XmlElement to adjust mapping

Comment: @Kamil.H Clearly not what OP asks. :)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this

Comment: Could you please also post the complex type which contains your element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`jaxb:property`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148590) customization to customize the property name.

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          version="2.1">

    <bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" version="1.0" node="/xs:schema">
        <bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='SOME_TYPE']">
            <bindings node="xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='REC_LOC']">
                <property name="RecLoc"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

(Not tested.)

See also:

- [`globalBindings/@enableJavaNamingConventions`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148515)
- [`nameXmlTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148550)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works fine, but this solution would imply adding a binding for each element in the xsd. I came across the plugin described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916398/how-can-i-get-jaxb2-to-emit-camelcase-bindings
which seems to do exactly what I need.