# create jaxb class which contains classes with same fields name

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Sorry for my dumb question, but I really need your help!

I need to create jaxb class which contains classes(from different third-party xsds(both chameleon), so I can't change them) with same fields name.
For example:
class from fist schema

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
public class A {    
private model.a.StatusType status;
private String operName;
//getters,setters ...
```

from second schema

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "B")
public class A {    
private model.b.StatusType status;
private String operName;
//getters,setters ...
```

In real there are more 100 same fields/
And I need to create class :

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"a","b"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Input")
public class Input {

private B b;
private A a;
```

that's problem, I got Exception:Two classes have the same XML type name
Any ideas how to combine class A and class B in my new class Input?

in case I create class Input I get exception 'com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "statusType" Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.'
But, in real I can't change xsd s which contains class A and class B

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize property name in JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039514/how-to-customize-property-name-in-jaxb)

Comment: using  <bindings.. is a problem, because in this case I have to write more than 100 bindigs

Comment: are these classes in one XSD file?

Comment: no, from 3 different chameleon schemas

Comment: I would then configure jaxb to generate output from different schemas to different packages. Then in your class I would use fully qualified names. See how to specify output package name for xjc generation: http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html

Comment: they have already in different packages and different projects

Comment: are they have different namespaces?

Comment: schema with class A and schema with class B doesn't have targetnamespase

Comment: can you post exception? it would be easier

Comment: added to question description