# JAXB translate element name when marshalling/un-marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am generating a java class from xsd which is used in to marshal/un-marshal xml.

I have an element currently defined in my xsd as

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="versionLabel" type="xs:string"/>
```

which results in a java class containing

```
String versionLabel
```

and setters and getters, *setVersionLabel()*/*getVersionLabel()*.

I want the incoming/outgoing xml element to be <version> and for that to translate to/from the java class property "versionLabel". How do I do define that behavior in the xsd?

Answer (score 0):

add @XmlElement annotation to the attribute and update your xsd if it used for any validation

```java
    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    String versionLabel;
```

Comment: How would you add this to the xsd? In my case the xsd is used to generate the java class. I just don't know how to add the @XmlElement attribute to the xsd.

Comment: you should update name="versionLabel" to name="version" in your xsd and add annotation to your java class

Comment: My only issue there is that my xsd generates my java class. So I need a way to add the annotation to the xsd so that the generated java class also gets the annotation.

Comment: you can use jaxb binding when you generate java class  check the next post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039514/how-to-customize-property-name-in-jaxb